# Filtrar contenido de otra tabla por parámetro - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estoy intentando hacer un link que me redirija a los resultados correspondiente a un parámetro. lo que tengo es una cuenta a la que le hago click y debería mostrarme el listado con todas las ventas que esa cuenta tiene. Acá les muestro el link que armé

`<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><%= link_to account.nombre, sales_path(:account_id => account.id) %></a>`

Y este es mi controlador

```
  before_action :set_account, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /accounts or /accounts.json
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
    @accounts = @accounts.where(["nombre LIKE :filter", :filter => "%" + params[:filter] + "%"]) unless params[:filter].blank?
    @accounts = @accounts = @accounts.where(:sale_id => params[:sale_id]) if params[:sale_id]
  end

  # GET /accounts/1 or /accounts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /accounts/new
  def new
    @account = Account.new
  end

  # GET /accounts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /accounts or /accounts.json
  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: "Account was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @account }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /accounts/1 or /accounts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.update(account_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: "Account was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @account }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /accounts/1 or /accounts/1.json
  def destroy
    @account.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to accounts_url, notice: "Account was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_account
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:nombre, :dni, :celular)
    end
end
```

No hay errores, pero cuando hago click para ver qué sale me muestra todas las ventas que tengo y no las correspondientes a ese cliente. espero su respuesta, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu controlador completo?

Comment: ¿Seguro es el controlador adecuado? Tu ruta parece estar apuntando al controlador `SalesController` y estás mostrando `AccountsController`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes conceptos errados. Primero con:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  <%= link_to account.nombre, sales_path(:account_id => account.id) %>
</a>
```

tienes un link (`link_to` que eventualmente te genera un `<a>`) anidado dentro de otro link (`<a>`), lo cual creo que no tiene mucho sentido. En el caso hipotético que dejases solo uno de ellos, por ejemplo solo `link_to account.nombre, sales_path(:account_id => account.id)`, eso te cargaría una nueva página y no te cargaría el contenido dentro de un modal (que es lo que asumo quieres hacer por lo de `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`).
Si quieres realmente cargar contenido de modo dinámico en vez de cargar una página completa, deberías empezar a hacer uso de llamadas ajax a través de js. Rails [tiene unas maneras simples de hacerlo](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) con `remote: true`, pero te aconsejo te leas el artículo entero para que entiendas completamente como interactua Rails con el frontend, porque también necesitarás algo de código en js.

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta. ya intenté trabajar con ajax y no encontré ninguna manera de hacerlo funcionar, todos los tutoriales que encontré están desactualizados.... estaba esperando encontrar una forma de hacerlo con otra alternativa

Comment: Pero el link que te compartí es de las guías oficiales de rails, eso no está desactualizado para nada. Y hay otras maneras, pero te aseguro que lo que sale en la guía es lo más simple de implementar.